# Syntax error in setTimeout() code

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a syntax error here for a script I'm working on. Can't exactly catch what it is. How does one make this one liner work?

```
setTimeout(function(){document.querySelector('#enterButton').click()}, 10000);}, 100);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line breaks help see the issue:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('#enterButton').click()
}, 10000);}, 100);
        //^^^ wtf is that!?
```

Only 1 interval needs to be specified:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('#enterButton').click()
}, 10000);
```

Comment: *"Line breaks help see the issue"* Quite. I almost want to ask the OP, "Do you actively dislike the person who has to maintain this code later?!" :-)